# How Do I Create a New Column From a Column Newly Added by a Join?

Tags: sql, sisense

Using a left join, I have brought together data from two tables.  From the data I brought in, I also created a new column using a logic statement (the AOIMonth column).

The question I have is, how do I create another column using another logic statement that references the new AOIMonth column?  The AOIMonth column is not declared in a table, so how can I reference that column?  Here's the code I have:

```
select c.*, b.[FirstMonth], b.[LastMonth], addmonths(b.[lastmonth], c.[Product AOI]) as AOIMonth

from [Churn Custom v4] c
left join (
        select[Line #1], min(Max_Month_Day) as [FirstMonth], max(Max_Month_Day) as 
        [LastMonth]
        from [Churn Custom v4]
        where [Invoiced_Flag]=1
        Group by [Line #1] ) b
    on c.[Line #1] = b.[Line #1]
order by c.[Max_Month_Day]
```

Basically, I want to say, "If AOIMonth = xyz, then abc else 0"  Thanks!

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using T-SQL? `addmonths` [isn't a T-SQL function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?search=addmonths&category=All&scope=sql).

Comment: @Larnu. . . It looks like `addmonths()` is a user defined function.

Comment: Possibly, @YogeshSharma, but then I would *expect* it to be prefixed by a schema. And then, why reinvent `DATEADD(MONTH...`? [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6a7f48c25a8cb024f2e5b73674f57504) notice the call to the function without the schema fails.

Comment: I'm fairly new to SQL, so I don't know what T-SQL is.  However, I'm using a BI tool called Sisense that is based on SQL and "addmonths" is a working function in the system.

Comment: If you don't know what T-SQL is, why did you tag it, @user12815408 ? T-SQL is the dialect of SQL specifically used by SQL Server (and Sybase) as the tag tells you. Tagging [tag:tsql] means you are saying you're using SQL Server (or Sybase).

Comment: Pretty sure I tagged just SQL and not TSQL.  But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat the expression.  You cannot re-use the alias, unless you use a subquery, CTE, or lateral join.

So:

```
(case when addmonths(b.[lastmonth], c.[Product AOI]) = xyz then abc else 0 end) as newcol
```

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense.  I tried that and it worked.  Thank you!

Comment: If this *is* T-SQL, the above won't run, as `addmonths` won't be recognised. A UDF must be prefixed by it's schema.